# Two simple [probably] coding questions

Tags: xml, eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="102dp"
    android:hint="@string/Please enter a department number." 
    android:inputType="number"
    />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="102dp"
    android:hint="@string/Or enter a department name." 
    android:inputType="string"
    />

    <requestFocus />


</LinearLayout>
```

**  Q#1. Right at the last line, i get Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag
    - This text field does not specify an inputType 
     or a hint.  Not sure what to do? **

```
package walmart.namespace;


import android.R;
import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WalmartActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

int department;
String name;
Button search;
TextView display;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

**q#2: For the R.Layout.main, i have 'main cannot be resolved or is not a field'.  I know i shouldn't use the import android.R in the imports, but it at least gets rid of the problem being the R. Any ideas on how to fix this?**

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, it looks like the  line should be placed within whichever EditText area you want to have focus; move it up to just after one of the inputType lines, and see if that helps.

For the second, I'm not sure if the code snippet has been truncated so this may not be the issue, but it looks like you're missing the curly braces to close onCreate.

Comment: Moving the <requestfocus /> into the code for the text view doesn't help.  As for the second question, the curly brace is at the end of the code.